# List view for user specific data?

Tags: django, django-views

I am a beginner in django . I am trying to get build a notesapp, but when a user logged in they are able to see all the all notes that are present in the admin panel. when I tried the below view function im just getting a blank page.How to write a view function such that a particular user can see the notes only they made .
I have the following

**views.py**

```
  @login_required(login_url='login')
  def Viewall(request):
     notes = NotesModel.objects.filter(user=request.user).all()
     return render(request, "Viewall.html", {'notes':notes})
```

**models.py**

```
class NotesModel(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)
    note=models.TextField()
    time=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**viewall.html**

```
{% for data in notes %}
    <div class="col">
        <div class="card note_card">
            <h5 class="card-header">{{ data.title }}</h5>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title"></h5>
              <p class="card-text">{{ data.note|truncatechars:50}}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: remove all(). Its not required. your code should be notes = NotesModel.objects.filter(user=request.user)

Comment: i tried its not working

Answer (score -1):

To display only the content owned by a specific user in the Django admin panel, you can customize the admin interface by creating a custom ModelAdmin class. Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import NotesModel

class NotesModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        # Retrieve the current logged-in user
        user = request.user

        # Filter the queryset to show only the user's own content
        queryset = super().get_queryset(request).filter(user=user)

        return queryset

admin.site.register(NotesModel, NotesModelAdmin)
```

Comment: i tried but its still giving me the same.